# User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, parquet

I'm implementing a spark java code as,
Dataset input = spark.read().parquet(configuration.getInputDataLocation());

But the the inputDataLocation(A folder in Azure Storage Account container) may not have any data and in such use cases exception is being thrown,
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.

Is there a brief way to check if the file folder is empty beforehand and then only I process the spark java code line written above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure you read the guidelines for a good post and edit your post. You will want to have a shorter title, a clearer description including code formatting, and a clear explanation of what you did, including code. If you don’t, other user may (and will!) downvote your question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try a read in the input dir to check if it exists?

```
       final boolean exists;
            try {
                exists = file.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration()).getFileStatus(file).isFile();

//exists = dir.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration()).listStatus(dir).length // (0 length is an empty dir)
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
    
            if (exists) {
                return spark.read().parquet(configuration.getInputDataLocation());
            } else {
                LOG.warn("File directory '{}' does not exist", file);
                return spark.emptyDataset(SOME_ENCODER);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the instance file referring to java.io.File?
because it needs a parameter to be passed inside of it and above that it doesn't have any function named getFileSystem();

Comment: file is an instance of `Path` from  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

Comment: hey, I tested youe solution and it works fine if the exact file path is provided but here I want to check if there are files inside a specified folder or not and how do we do it.

Comment: Added a comment in the code to read dir